# Where does this index come from?

Tags: oracle, index

Looking for some index in one schema I get to create, I found one index with prefix `sys_` such as below:

```
SQL> select index_name from dba_indexes where owner = 'DANILO';

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
INDEX_SALES_ID
SYS_C0010892
```

Indeed, I didn't create this index, Why do I have it in my schema?

Comment: You can pull more columns from dba_index to get a better idea what that index is for:   eg:    select owner, index_name, index_type, table_owner, table_name, uniqueness, status from dba_indexes where owner = 'DANILO';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an index that was automatically generated for a constraint. Example:

```
SQL> select index_name from user_indexes;

no rows selected

SQL> create table t1(c1 number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes;

INDEX_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_C006380
```

Comment: Other possibilities are Nested Tables or LOB objects, there Oracle also creates indexes automatically.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Nested table: yes, LOB: kind of, because LOB indexes follow a different naming convention.